# Pandas: speed up df.loc based on repeat index values

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have the pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'y': [1, 2, 2],
    'z': ['f', 's', 's']
}).set_index('x')
```

from which I would like to select rows based on values of the index (`x`) in the selection array

```
selection = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

The correct output can be obtained by using `df.loc` as follows

```
out = df.loc[selection]
```

The problem I am running in to is `df.loc` is running pretty slow on large DataFrames (2-7 million rows). Is there a way to speed up this operation? I've looked into `eval()`, but it doesn't seem to apply to hard-coded lists of index values like this. I have also thought about using `pd.DataFrame.isin`, but that misses the repeat values (only returns a row per unique element in `selection`).

Comment: you could get rid of dupes in selection.

Comment: @riotburn dupes are necessary for the application

Comment: how is it necessary for selecting rows where the index is in one of selection?  Can't do `df.loc[list(set(selection))]`?

Comment: No, the duplicates are on purpose. `out` is the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a decent speedup by using `reindex` instead of `loc`:

```
df.reindex(selection)
```

Timings (version 0.17.0):

```
>>> selection2 = selection * 100 # a larger list of labels
>>> %timeit df.loc[selection2]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df.reindex(selection2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 833 µs per loop
```

The two methods take different paths (hence the speed difference).

`loc` builds the new DataFrame by calling down to
[`get_indexer_non_unique`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/index.pyx#l283) which is necessarily more complex than the simple [`get_indexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/index.pyx#l279) (used for unique values).

On the other hand, the hard work in `reindex` appears to be done by the `take_*` functions in [generated.pyx](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/78fcce40c4e19f8e3a1b32d103c56c52124c284a/pandas/src/generated.pyx). These functions appear to be faster for the purpose of constructing the new DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `merge`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'y': [1, 2, 2],
    'z': ['f', 's', 's']
})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':selection})

In [21]: pd.merge(df1,df,on='x', how='left')
Out[21]: 
   x  y  z
0  a  1  f
1  c  2  s
2  b  2  s
3  b  2  s
4  c  2  s
5  a  1  f
```